# remove zero padding effects of 1D convolution

Tags: matlab, convolution

I've written a simple 1D gaussian filter that I'm convolving with some signal data to produce a smooth trace. The only problem is that when I convolve the data I get major drop near the start and end points of my smoothed signal data. When I plot the data it just warps my graph because it's trying to plot signal values that are like 10 at the start and end, when all my other data is like 10,000-13,000.

Anyone know of any ways to circumvent this/ prevent zero padding of the convolution?

Heres my code:

`smooth_signal = conv2(signal_full, 1d_gaus,'same');`

Where my input `signal_full` is a 1055x1 double matrix.

Comment: Normally you'd take just the `1055` samples from the center of the output.

Comment: Why `conv2` and not `conv`?  What is `1d_gaus`? seems that this variable effects the results, try to adjust it. And, I think that "zero padding" is not the term, or i didn't get your question.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think that the `same` propety should do it automatically

Comment: True.  Have you seen the other option `'valid'
Returns only those parts of the convolution that are computed without the zero-padded edges.`

Comment: Ok so `1d_gaus` is just the output of a 1D gaussian function, based on an x of -20:20 and a sigma of 5, so a 41x1 double matrix. Basically what I have at the moment is some noisy signal data that needs to be smoothed and plotted against some time data that starts at 0 seconds and ends at 1000s. 

Just tried the `'valid'` option of the `conv` function (Adiel is quite right, I don't need to do the `conv2` function) However this outputs only a 990 x 1 signal matrix, how would I adjust my time data so it matches up with my new 990 element smoothed signal?

Comment: You lost the zero padding of convolution, due to using `valid`, so the signal get shorted (I think you have to get output of 1 x 1015 for these inputs...). Anyway, you actually used a FIR filter with 41 samples, so the time-delay is 20 seconds. The time of the output is now 21-1010 seconds.

Comment: maybe you want symmetric padding? https://gist.github.com/cyrilauburtin/192c95cccddfa45f25f3

Answer (score 1):

Use `nanconv.m` instead ([File Exchange link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41961-nanconv)), with the 'edge' input argument. This handles timepoints beyond the boundaries as missing values instead of zeros, hence eliminating edge effects.